# My SB 700 is not working with my nikon D7000

Tags: nikon, flash, nikon-d7000, sb-700

Until recently my Nikon SB700 flash and D7000 were working fine together, but now when I connect the flash I see a message on the screen of the flash to change to manual mode (as it is not working in TTL). I haven't tried it yet with another camera, but it says in the flash's manual that the "move to manual mode" message means it is incompatible with the camera.

What could be happening?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the contacts on both the camera's hot shoe and the flash's foot?

Comment: Check the seating of the flash in the hotshoe; and check the batteries in the flash.